# OOPS Concepts: What is the difference in passing object reference to interface and creating class object in C#?

Tags: c#, class, interface

I have a class, `CustomerNew`, and an interface, `ICustomer`:

```
public class CustomerNew : ICustomer
{
    public void A()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Class method");
    }

    void ICustomer.A()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Interface method");
    }


    public void B()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Class Method");
    }
}

public interface ICustomer
{
    void A();
}
```

I am very confused between these two code of lines.

```
ICustomer objnew = new CustomerNew();
CustomerNew objCustomerNew = new CustomerNew();
objnew.B(); // Why this is wrong?
objCustomerNew.B(); // This is correct because we are using object of class
```

The first line of code means we are passing object reference of CustomerNew class in `objnew`, am I correct? If yes, then why can I not access method B() of the class with `interface objnew`?

Can someone explain about these two in detail.

Comment: There is no `B()` method on `ICustomer`.

Comment: Yes I understand, but i want to know how these two lines works. what exactly the difference? or you can say what exactly happens when we write those two lines for object refernce.

Comment: `objCustomerNew` has type `CustomerNew` which has a `B()` method so `objCustomerNew.B()` is valid. `objnew` has type `ICustomer` which does not have a `B()` method so `objnew.B()` is invalid.

Comment: We can not create object of interface, but we can pass reference of object to an interface. So if we are passing reference of object of my class then why B is not accessible ? I mean reference types hold reference then do Interface types matters ? I agree with your points that ``objnew `` is of type ``ICustomer`` but still it contains reference of our class object on heap , right....this is making confusion. Can you elaborate by answering this question in detail.

Comment: You need to ask yourself why upcasting (to `ICustomer`) in the first place, then you'll understand why even though it "still contains reference of our class object on heap" it cannot be treated as the concrete type (`CustomerNew`).

Comment: It doesn't matter what the runtime type of the reference is. The compiler cares only about what's defined in compile-time - and you've explicitly said "this variable can contain any object that implements `ICustomer`". And of course, under Liskov's Substitution Principle, any type that implements `ICustomer` should work just as well. When you tell the compiler to discard the type information, don't complain that it was discarded!

Comment: @Gaurav123 the terminology you are using is wrong and probably confusing you. You're not "passing a reference" of anything to the interface, that's not how it works. The interface is merely a "different view" of the object you created, and you can only use things present in that "view".

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks to understand the problem :-)   ``ICustomer objnew = new CustomerNew(); `` means we are creating instance of the class and then objnew contains reference of this object , is it incorrect ? so whats exactly happening, please continue ..you might be able to clear more points

Comment: @Gaurav123 The compiler is obligated to treat objNew as an ICustomer.  Even though it has enough information here, theoretically, to know that objNew is really a CustomerNew, it's not supposed to care.  As far as what the compiler is supposed to be acting as, objNew could be a reference to an object of a different class entirely, one without a B().

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually an interface is also a type (you can't create instances of interfaces since they'are just metadata).

Since `CustomerNew` implements `ICustomer`, an instance of `CustomerNew` can be *upcasted* to `ICustomer`. When a `CustomerNew` is typed as `ICustomer` you can only access `ICustomer` members.

This is because C# is a strongly-typed language, thus, in order to access a particular member (i.e. methods, properties, events...) you need an object reference to be qualified by the type which defines the members you want to access *(i.e. you need to store `CustomerNew` object in a reference of type `CustomerNew` to access the method `B`)*.

### Update

OP said:

> So due to upcasting we can only access those methods which are inside
>   interface, correct ? UPCASTING is the main reason behind this ?

Yes. An easy explanation is an object which implements `ICustomer` shouldn't mandatorily be `CustomerNew`. You need to *downcast* an `ICustomer` reference to `CustomerNew` to be able to access `CustomerNew` members.

As both classes and interfaces are types, and C# is a strongly-typed language, you access object members by providing its actual type. This is why you need to use *casts*.

For example, your code does an implicit upcast:

```
// This is an implicit cast that's equivalent to
// ICustomer objnew = (ICustomer)new CustomerNew()
ICustomer objnew = new CustomerNew();
```

Implicit upcasts are possible because the compiler already knows `CustomerNew` implements `ICustomer` introspecting `CustomerNew` metadata, while you can't implictly-*downcast* a `ICustomer` reference because who knows who implements `ICustomer`? It can be either `CustomerNew` or any other class or even an struct:

```
ICustomer asInterface = new CustomerNew();

// ERROR: This won't compile, you need to provide an EXPLICIT DOWNCAST
CustomerNew asClass1 = asInterface;

// OK. You're telling the compiler you know that asInterface
// reference is guaranteed to be a CustomerNew too!
CustomerNew asClass2 = (CustomerNew)asInterface;
```

If you're not sure that an `ICustomer` is a `CustomerNew`, you can use the `as` operator, which won't throw an exception during run-time if the cast isn't possible:

```
// If asInterface isn't also a CustomerNew, the expression will set null
CustomerNew asClass3 = asInterface as CustomerNew;
```

Comment: So due to ``upcasting`` we can only access those methods which are inside interface, correct ? ``UPCASTING`` is the main reason behind this ?

Comment: Yes, you can understand from this point of view. It's like creating sub-groups of members. If you type A, you have base class members, if you type B which inherits A, you have all members from A and B, and so on. This also works with interfaces.

Comment: @Gaurav123 In order to access members from more derived classes or whatever, you need to *downcast* the reference again.

Comment: @Gaurav123 See my update. I give you a full explanation about the topic ;)

Comment: @Gaurav123  I've re-updated the update. I believe that my explanation should point you in the right direction for now

Comment: Awesome...this is the exact answer. Thanks,
Now the concept is very much cleared.

Comment: @Gaurav123 You're welcome! I'm glad you've the concept clear in your mind :)

Comment: So ``Implicit upcasts`` done the trick. Once this is understood we can find all answers are useful but missed this key point ``IMPLICIT UPCAST ``.

Comment: @Gaurav123 Yeah, I know this. Other answers are absolutely valid content, but I believe they try to fix more *what's an interface* rather than how object typing works. In my case I prefered to focus on this topic rather than a book-like composition about what's an interface and how they should be used, which is off-topic to your question (or this is my feeling so far...)

Answer (score 28):

Interfaces have many features and usages but one central thing is the ability to present functionality to the outside world in an agreed upon contract.

Let me give you an example. Consider a soda vending machine. It has a slot or two for you to input coins, a few buttons for you to choose the right type of soda and a button to dispense the soda (unless the choice button also does that).

Now, this is an *interface*. This hides the complexity of the machine behind the interface and presents a few choices to you.

But, and here is the important part, *internally* the machine has a lot of functionality and it may even have other buttons and knobs, typically there for the maintenance people to test or operate the machine when there is something wrong, or when they have to empty it for money or fill it with soda.

This part of the machine is hidden from you, you only get access to whatever the creators of the external interface added to that interface.

You don't even know how the machine actually operates behind the scenes. I could create a new vending machine that teleports sodas in from a nearby factory and teleports the coins you added directly to the bank and you would be none the wiser. Not to mention that I would be rich, but that's another story.

So, back to your code.

You explicitly declared `objnew` as `ICustomer`. Whatever you put *behind* this interface is hidden. You only get access to whatever it is that is declared *as part of that interface*.

The other variable was declared as having the type of the underlying object, as such you have full access to all of its public functionality. Think of it like unlocking the vending machine and using it with the front open.

Answer (score 7):

In the first line:

```
ICustomer objnew
```

You're instructing the compiler to treat `objnew` as `ICustomer` and since the interface does not declare a `B()` method, it errors.

In the second line:

```
CustomerNew objCustomerNew
```

You're referring to `objCustomerNew` as `CustomerNew` and since it does specify a `B()` method it compiles just fine.

Comment: I agree :) even I know this. but my question is something in deeper level. I mean please read my last comment under my question and try to put more details so that everyone can get benefit from the same.

Comment: @Gaurav123 a comment should not be a key part of the question you want answered.  This explains they question you asked pretty well.  If you want more details, like what you included in the comment, then it should be part of your question

Answer (score 4):

This has everything to do with compile-time (i.e. static) type checking.  If you look at the two lines

```
ICustomer objnew = new CustomerNew();
objnew.B();
```

you can clearly see that the object that `objnew` refers to has a `B()` method, so you know that there would be no problem at run time with the second line.

But, that is not how the compiler looks at it. The compiler uses a set of fairly simple rules to figure out whether to report an error. When it looks a the call `objnew.B()` it uses the static (i.e. declared) type of `objnew` to determine the type of the recipient.  The static (declared) type is `ICustomer`, and that type doesn't declare a `B()` method, so there is an error reported.

So why does the compiler ignore the initial value given to the reference?  Here are two reasons:

First: Because it can't use that information in general because --in general-- there could be intervening conditional assignments. For example you might have code that looks like this

```
ICustomer objnew = new CustomerNew();
if( some complicated expression ) objnew = new CustomerOld() ;
objnew.B();
```

where `CustomerOld` is some class that implements the interface but has no `B()` method.

Second: There might be no initialization expression. This happens in particular with parameters. When the compiler compiles a method it has no access to the set of all calls to the method. Consider

```
void f( ICustomer objnew ) {
    objnew.B(); 
}
```

To keep the rules simple, the same rules are used for parameters as for (other) variables.

You could certainly imagine a language where the rules are different, but this is how C#, Java, and similar languages work.

Answer (score 3):

Your `objnew` variable is a reference to an object that implements `ICustomer`. Be aware of the fact, that this could be **any** object, as long as it implements `ICustomer`. So all that is exposed by this reference, are the members of ICustomer, which is only the method `A()` in your example.

If you do want to access the `B()` method of the object that is referenced by `objnew`, you will have to explicitly convert it to a `CustomerNew` reference (that's C#'s type safety at work), like e.g. that:

```
CustomerNew objCustomerNew = objnew as CustomerNew;
objCustomerNew.B();
```

or

```
(objnew as CustomerNew).B();
```

Keep in mind that `objnew` could be of any type implementing `ICustomer`, thus the conversion `objnew as CustomerNew` could resolve to `null` if you implement other `ICustomer` classes later.

Answer (score 1):

In Simple words I would say that **objnew** is a variable of type **ICustomer** which contains a reference of type **CustomerNew**. Since **ICustomer** doesn't have the declaration or definition(which it can't have as it is an interface) of the method **B()** which compiler checks at compile time and it throws a compile type error.

Now coming to the explanation, at compile time compiler checks the MethodDef table of the Type of the variable i.e. **ICustomer** and walks up the hierarchy level of class definition. If it finds the method in the definition table it would refer to the method which has been found(which again depend on other scenarios like overriding which we can discuss in other topic). This we can understand using a simple example which I want to discuss here

```
public interface IMyInterface
{

}

public class MyBaseClass:IMyInterface
{
    public string B()
    {
        return "In Abstract";
    }
}

public class MyDerivedClass : MyBaseClass
{

}
```

Kindly go though the class hierarchy in the above code snippet. Now coming to the implementation part as shown below,

```
        MyBaseClass inst = new MyDerivedClass();
        inst.B(); //Works fine 

        MyDerivedClass inst1 = new MyDerivedClass();
        inst1.B(); //Works fine

        IMyInterface inst2 = new MyDerivedClass();
        inst2.B(); //Compile time error
```

Scenario 1 works fine for the obvious reason as I have explained earlier which is, **inst** is variable of type **MyBaseClass** which contains a reference of type **MyDerivedClass** and **MyBaseClass** has definition of method B().

Now coming to scenario 2, it also works fine but how? **inst1** is a variable of type **MyDerivedClass** which contains a variable again of type **MyDerivedClass** but method B() is not defined in this type, but what compiler does is it checks at compile time the MethodDef table of **MyDerivedClass** and finds that **MyBaseClass** has definition if the Method B() which it refers at run time.

So by now I hope you got my point which explains why scenario 3 will not work.